# $\mathbb E[X]=0$ implies existence of two random variables $Y\stackrel{\mathrm d}=Z$, equal in distribution, such that $X\stackrel{\mathrm d}=Y-Z$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request

Let $X$ be a bounded random variable on a non-atomic probability space, i.e. $X\in L^\infty(\mathbb P)$, such that $\mathbb E[X]=0$. In a lecture, I heard someone claim that this implies the existence of two other random variables $Y,Z\in L^\infty(\mathbb P)$ such that $Y\stackrel{\mathrm d}=Z$ and $X\stackrel{\mathrm d}=Y-Z$, although they claimed the proof was difficult and tedious.

Is this result even true? Even in simple examples I don't really see what this decomposition should look like. What is the intuition behind such a result? Is there perhaps a proof in the literature or in a textbook?

Comment: It's certainly not true if you add the restriction that $Y,Z$ are independent.

Comment: This is supposed to be true in any probability space? Or in a specific probability space?

Comment: @DarkMalthorp I do not assume $Y,Z$ are independent.

Comment: @jwhite Thanks! I forgot to mention that we work with non-atomic r.v.s

Comment: $A \stackrel{\mathrm d}= B$ implies $|| A-B ||_1 = 0$ ie $L_1$ equivalent? If so I'm really not seeing how this could be true.

Comment: @user24142 you're claim is not correct, for $A,B$ are allowed to be dependent.

Comment: e.g. take $A$ standard normal, $B=-A$, $A-B=2A$, which of course has zero expectation but $\|A\|_{L^1}=\mathbb E|A|>0$

Comment: okay, what is the meaning of that notation then?

Comment: Well, clearly if X is symmetrically distributed, we can take Z=-X/2 and Y=X/2. So the difficulty is for X no symmetric.

Comment: @user24142 $\stackrel{\mathrm d}=$ denotes equality in distribution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an attempt at a proof. I don't have a reference, or much intuition beyond this construction.

Consider first the case of a variable $X$ taking the value $a<0$ with probability $b/(|a|+b)$ and
taking the value $b>0$ with probability $|a|/(|a|+b).$ Pick random variables $Y,Z$ uniformly distributed on $[a,b],$ with $Y=Z+b$ when $Z<0$ and $Y=Z+a$ when $Z\geq 0.$ Then $Y-Z\stackrel{\mathrm d}= X$ as required.

For the general case we can take a mixture, by pairing up the events $X<0$ and $X>0$ in a suitable way.

**Remark.** We just need to write the law of $X$ as a weighted average of zero-mean probability distributions supported on two points. A slick way to do this is to use [Choquet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choquet_theory#Choquet%27s_theorem) and a characterization of extreme points of the set of zero-mean variables, e.g. Winkler's  ["Extreme Points of Moment Sets"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3689944). The remainder of this answer is just a more explicit version of this.

Let $\mu$ be the law of $X.$ Let $M=\tfrac 1 2 \mathbb E|X|.$
There exists a Borel function $f^+:[0,M]\to\mathbb R_{>0}$ such that the pushforward of Lebesgue measure $f^+_*\lambda$ is the measure $x d\mu(x).$
For example, the [generalized inverse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Inverse_distribution_function_(quantile_function)) of the function $t\mapsto \int_0^t x d\mu(x).$
Similarly there exists a Borel function $f^-:[0,M]\to\mathbb R_{<0}$ such that $f^-_*\lambda$ is the measure $|x| d\mu(x).$
The pushforward of $(1/f^+(x))d\lambda(x)$ under $f^+$ is $\mu$ restricted to $\mathbb R_{>0}.$
And similarly the pushforward of $(1/|f^-(x)|)d\lambda(x)$ under $f^-$ is $\mu$ restricted to $\mathbb R_{<0}.$

Pick independent random variables $R,S,T$ such that

- $R$ is a Bernoulli random variable with $\mathbb P[R=0]=\mathbb P[X=0],$
- $S$ is a random variable on $[0,M]$ distributed according to the measure $((1/f^+(x))+(1/|f^-(x)|))d\lambda(x),$
- $T$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1].$

Then define $Y$ and $Z$ by:

- wherever $R=0,$ we take $Y=Z=0,$ and skip the next steps.
- $Z$ is $T$ rescaled from $[0,1]$ to the interval $[f^-(S),f^+(S)].$
- $Y$ is $Z+f^+(S)$ when $Z<0$
- $Y$ is $Z+f^-(S)$ when $Z\geq 0.$

$Z$ has the same distribution as $Y.$
The random variable $Y-Z$ has the same probability of being zero as $X.$
For any Borel $U\subseteq\mathbb R_{>0},$ the probability that $f^+(S)\in U$ and $Y-Z=f^+(S)$ is $\int (1/f^+(x))1_{f^+(x)\in U}d\lambda(x)=\mu(U).$
So the laws of $Y-Z$ and $X$ are the same on $\mathbb R_{>0}$.
And similarly for $\mathbb R_{<0}.$
So this construction ensures $Y-Z\stackrel{\mathrm d}= X.$

Comment: This looks difficult but not tedious at all.

Comment: This looks fine to me, and I bet this construction is way simpler than the `tedious' proof talked about in the lecture. Thanks for your inventive answer, +1, and I leave the bounty open to allow for other answers as well.

Comment: @ColinMcQuillan the authors of the paper giving the lecture wish to thank you properly for this contribution in the next iteration of their paper. If interested, please contact the first author of https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.09173